# Integrate $ \int \frac { e^{\arctan(x)}}{{(1+x^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$y=arctanx$
$tany=x$

\begin{align}
\int \frac { e^{\Large\arctan(x)}}{{(1+x^2)}^{\Large\frac{3}{2}}} \ dx&=\int \frac {e^{\Large\arctan(\tan y)}}{{(1+\tan^2y)}^{\Large\frac{3}{2}}}dy\\
&=\int \frac {e^{y}}{\sec^3 y} dy\\
&= e^y \cos^3 y+ \int 3e^{y}\sin y\ \cos^2 y\ dy\\
\end{align}

Is this right so far or am I doing something wrong?
It's been quite a while since I've done integration with trig substitutions. Last time I did this integral I did not use trig subtitution and still got the correct answer, I can't find my solutions from then(over 2 years ago).

Comment: You need to change the integration measure as well, $dx=\sec^2{y} \, dy$.

Comment: Lol, I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your substitution gives
$$ I = \int \frac{e^y}{(1+\tan^2{y})^{3/2}} \sec^2{y} \, dy = \int e^y \cos{y} \, dy, $$
which we work out by integrating by parts a couple of times to be
$$ \frac{1}{2}e^y(\cos{y}+\sin{y})=\frac{1}{2}e^y \cos{y}(1+\tan{y}) = \frac{e^{\arctan{x}}}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}(1+x) $$

---

You can also do this by parts without substitution: the derivative of $e^{\arctan{x}}$ is $e^{\arctan{x}}/(1+x^2)$, so you have
$$ I = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\frac{e^{\arctan{x}}}{1+x^2} \, dx \\
= \frac{e^{\arctan{x}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + \int \frac{x e^{\arctan{x}}}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \, dx $$
If you do this again, you get
$$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \frac{e^{\arctan{x}}}{1+x^2} \, dx = \frac{xe^{\arctan{x}}}{1+x^2} - \int \frac{e^{\arctan{x}}}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \left( 1+x^2-x^2 \right) \, dx, $$
and $I$ has reappeared on the right, so solving for $I$ gives
$$ I = \frac{1+x}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}e^{\arctan{x}} $$
as before.

Comment: $+C$ a few times.

Answer (score 4):

You may observe that
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\right)'=\frac {x}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}},\quad \left(\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\right)'=\frac {1}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}},
$$
then just perform two integrations by parts as follows.
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac { e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}}dx&=\frac {x\: e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{1/2}}-\int \frac { x\:e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}} \ dx\\\\
&=\frac {x\: e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{1/2}}-\left(-\frac { e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{1/2}}+\int \frac { e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}} \ dx\right)\\\\
&=\frac {(x+1)\: e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{1/2}}-\int \frac { e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}} \ dx
\end{align}$$ giving easily
$$\bbox[30px,border:1px solid #ff8000]{
\begin{align}
\int \frac { e^{\Large\arctan x}}{{(1+x^2)}^{3/2}}dx=\frac {(x+1)\: e^{\Large\arctan x}}{2(1+x^2)^{1/2}}+C.
\end{align}}
$$